# use of break in java

Tags: java, loops, label, break

For nested loops, when I use `continue` with labels it gives me an error during compilation saying that `the declared loop is not present`.

Particularly for this case, the error message being displayed is: `Second is not a loop label`.

Here's the piece of code I have written to demonstrate my problem:

```
//using break as a form of GOTO 
class demo
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {   
        boolean b=false;
        First:{
            Second:{
                Third:{
                        System.out.println("Before BReak");
                        if(b)                               
                        continue Third;                 
                        else
                        break Second;
                    }
                    System.out.println("THis won't execute");
                }
                System.out.println("THis too won't Execute");
            }
    }   

}
```

Comment: What is first second third exactly?

Comment: I'm not seeing any loops...

Answer (score 3):

As you're not in a loop of some sort, you can't use `continue`.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while ,
>   or do-while loop

Answer (score 0):

This results in compilation error in Java, because there is no loop. continue makes sense only when there is the loop

Answer (score 0):

you Can use Label statement without loop only with break and not with continue

- for using continue you would require a loop
- an example of the label statement  without a loop and break statement:

  sumBlock: 
  {

  ```
       if (a < 0) {
              break sumBlock;
          }

          if (b < 0) {
              break sumBlock;
          }
          return a + b;
      }
  ```